# Converting a list to integers

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, replace, integer

here is the problem:
Write a program that computes and prints the average of the numbers in a text file. You should make use of two higher-order functions to simplify the design.

An example of the program input and output is shown below:

Enter the input file name: numbers.txt

The average is 69.83333333333333

here are the numbers in numbers.txt:
45 66 88
100 22 98

and here is my code:

```
    file = input("Enter the input file name: ")
    with open(file) as f:
        from functools import reduce
        def add(x, y): return x + y
        data = [45, 66, 88, 100, 22, 98]
        total = reduce(add, data)
        avg = total / len(data)
        print("The average is: ", avg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

the problem is, this works fine when I manually enter items in a list, but when I added the line.strip function and tried to put it in a list, and then convert it using map, this is my code:

```
    file = input("Enter the input file name: ")
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            data = [line]
        data = list(map(int, data))
        from functools import reduce
        def add(x, y): return x + y
        total = reduce(add, data)
        avg = total / len(data)
        print("The average is: ", avg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "average.py", line 15, in <module>
    main()
  File "average.py", line 7, in main
    data = list(map(int, data))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '100 22 98'
```

I am terrible at coding, can you please help me understand 1) what the error is 2) is there something wrong with the list not converting the strings to integers?

Thank you!

Comment: Change this line: `data = list(map(int, data))` to `data = list(map(int, data.split()))`

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with below line of code, this is not spliting the line and adding each item to list. it is adding whole line as an string in list.

```
data = [line]
```

e.g.

```
data = [line]

['11 12 123 123']

data = line.split()

['11', '12', '123', '123']
```

You need to change your code like below and it should work.

```
file = input("Enter the input file name: ")
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        data = line.split()
    data = list(map(int, data))
    from functools import reduce
    def add(x, y): return x + y
    total = reduce(add, data)
    avg = total / len(data)
    print("The average is: ", avg)
```